# How to scroll by percentage in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, scroll

I have a horizontally scrollable flexbox like this.

[image: example]

Each box width is 25%. I'm trying to scroll left and right using buttons. Now it scrolls by 420px as in the code, But this causes responsive issues. Is there any way to use "25%" instead of "420" in react.

```js
const scrollLeftHandler = () => {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("programCard");
    if (elmnt.scrollLeft !== 0) {
      elmnt.scrollLeft += -420;
      setIsRightSlide(true);
    } else {
      setIsLeftSlide(false);
    }
  };
  const scrollRightHandler = () => {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("programCard");
    if (elmnt.scrollLeft % 420 === 0 && isRightSlide) {
      console.log("if");
      setIsLeftSlide(true);
      elmnt.scrollLeft += 420;
    } else if (isRightSlide) {
      elmnt.scrollLeft = elmnt.scrollLeft - (elmnt.scrollLeft % 420);
      elmnt.scrollLeft += 420;
      setIsRightSlide(false);
    } else {
      console.log("else", elmnt.scrollLeft);
      setIsRightSlide(false);
    }
```

Comment: You have to calculate 25% off total width

Comment: this question has nothing to do with React. it's only logic, nothing is rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
let step = (window.innerWidth || docElem.clientWidth || body.clientWidth)*(25/100)
```

You can replace `420` with `step`.

Comment: You assume the scroll is on the `window` level and not internally. also you're not modifying the scroll at all, just doing plain math without the rest of the answer. A more generic, full solution would be nicer for future-dvelopers who might come seeking such